# What is the purpose of protected branches in GitLab when you can bypass the protection with a merge?

Tags: git, gitlab

GitLab has protected branches that only allow those with the "Maintainer" permission the ability to push a commit directly to the master branch; however, if someone has "Developer" permission they can simply create a merge request for their feature branch and then approve of their own merge which effectively bypasses the branch protection.

Comment: If the developer does not have  the permission "allowed to merge", the developer can't approve the merge request.

Answer (score 2):

First : you only describe the default settings for protected branches, there are several options you can choose from in the "Protected branches" settings.

Second : going through Merge requests adds a lot of features, which wouldn't be available if you allowed direct pushes :

- tracability : with a Merge request, gitlab keeps a trace of what users executed the actions "open a Merge request" and "accept the Merge request" -- when running `git push`, the data in the commits don't keep track of who executed the command,
- you can set validation steps (number of approvers, pipelines ...) on Merge requests,
- or simply choose a policy of what should be validated by peer review, and use Merge requests to keep a log of how it was applied (e.g : "who signed off on that change ?")